# Why does macOS Monterey not enable cmd/⌘-H "hide" an application when it's the only one that's not hidden?

Tags: macos, applications, dock

Hiding the current application with `cmd/⌘-H` does not work when current app is only non-hidden one, but does work when there are other, non-hidden applications. Why? And is there some way to make it work?

I just discovered this when upgrading from Catalina to Monterey. I've been using macOS for at least 10 years, and `cmd/⌘-H` has *always* hidden the current application, even when said app is the only non-hidden one.

`cmd-option-H` (which hides all the non-current applications) appears to work just fine.

My OS version running on my MacBook:

```
$ sw_vers
ProductName:    macOS
ProductVersion: 12.6.1
BuildVersion:   21G217
$
```

Answer (score 2):

In macOS, there has to be a current application to receive they keystrokes etc.

This application generates the menu. So for those who think that you used to be able to hide all the applications - what did the menu bar show?

Thus you cannot hide everything. So you can't hide the only application.

Comment: Previous-to-v12.6.3 macOS versions were able to hide the "last, non-hidden" application. I can't remember which ones, but it used to work.

Comment: Again what did the menu show. - as far as IO remeber NeXTStep could not hide all the apps so when was it introduced?

Comment: You're asking me to remember from months/years ago what the macOS-prev-v12 menu showed? I can not go from (my human) memory, and I no longer have that OS running.

Comment: I just tried to replicate this with both 10.6.8 and 13.3.1, the behavior is the same on both: If Finder and another app are running and both are not hidden, hiding the app is possible and switches back to Finder. But if Finder itself is hidden and the app is active, the "Hide" option is disabled as there is no other app (Finder) available to activate.